# No identifier/primary key specified for Entity why using KNP Translatable

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I am using `Knp/DoctrineBehaviors` to translate my database content.
I followed the [manual](https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors/blob/master/docs/translatable.md) and created 2 entities, 1 for non-translatable content and the other for translatable fields.

```
namespace App\Entity;


use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Contract\Entity\TranslatableInterface;
use Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Model\Translatable\TranslatableTrait;

    /**
     * Class Test
     * @package App\Entity
     * @ORM\Entity()
     */
    class Test implements TranslatableInterface
    {

        use TranslatableTrait;

        /**
         * @var integer
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         * @ORM\Id()
         */
        private $id;

        /**
         * @return int
         */
        public function getId(): int
        {
            return $this->id;
        }

        /**
         * @param int $id
         */
        public function setId(int $id): void
        {
            $this->id = $id;
        }




    }
```

and the Translation entity:

```
namespace App\Entity;


use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Contract\Entity\TranslationInterface;
use Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Model\Translatable\TranslationTrait;

/**
 * Class TestTranslation
 * @package App\Entity
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class TestTranslation implements TranslationInterface
{

    use TranslationTrait;

    /**
     * @var
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $name
     */
    public function setName($name): void
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }


}
```

I also added the Bundle in my **bundles.php** file.

But when I run the command `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force` to create the table in give the error: `No identifier/primary key specified for Entity "App\Entity\TestTranslation". Every Entity must have an identifier/p     rimary key.`

Answer (score 1):

In my case, Symfony 3.4, I forgot to register the bundle and set the config.yml as:

```
knp_doctrine_behaviors:
    translatable:   true
```

Answer (score 0):

A primary key is missing in your entity "TestTranslation". 
In doctrine every entity class must have an identifier/primary key. You can select the field that serves as the identifier with the @Id() annotation or in your case : @ORM\Id().

For example, add this to your entity :

```
/**
* @var integer
* @ORM\Column(type="integer")
* @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
* @ORM\Id()
*/
private $id;
```

And then, you can play the command: `php bin/console d:s:u --force`